# OCaml Streams: exception handling or Option types?

Tags: exception, stream, try-catch, ocaml

To handle exceptional cases in OCaml, it is often possible to choose to either catch exceptions or to use the type `'a option`.  If I understand correctly, both choices are possible for Streams thanks to the functions `Stream.next` (raises an exception) and `Stream.peek`/`Stream.junk` (return `'a option`).

Is there any difference between

```
match Stream.peek t with
| None -> ***
| Some c -> Stream.junk t; *****
```

and

```
try
  let c = Stream.next t in *****
with Stream.Failure -> ***
```

where `t` is a variable of type `'a stream` and `***` and `*****` are some sequences of expressions?

**Edit 2020-12-03**

Since OCaml 4.02, it is also possible to write the above as

```
match Stream.next t with
| c -> *****
| exception Stream.Failure -> ***
```

which may be preferable if further pattern matching is to be done on `c`, e.g.,

```
match Stream.next t with
| [] -> *****
| a::b -> *******
| exception Stream.Failure -> ***
```

(source: Xavier Leroy's slides What's new in OCaml 4.02).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in behavior, as you note.

The version with an option type will cons up some more data, as it has to create `Some x` for each value returned. This will be a minor effect in general because OCaml is excellent at garbage collecting short-lived values.

I personally like using options because of the parallelism between the two cases. But using `peek` and `junk` seems quite a bit clunkier than just having a function that returns an option. So for this case I might use the exception-based handling.

In other words, it's a judgement call (in my opinion).